# how to delete the directory which was created by the mount uploader manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I want to delete the directory which was created by the mount uploader manually. I have ArtistProduct and ArtistImage models. I want to delete the images which is stored in the file via artist product controller. I tried carrier this:

```
@art_images=ArtistImage.where("product_id=?",params[:id])
@art_images.each do |img|
img.remove_image!
 end
 @art_images.delete_all
```

But Image is not getting deleting. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will delete directory from your file system.

```
FileUtils.remove_dir("path to directory(which is to be deleted)/directoryname(to be deleted)", :force => true)
```